# How to log the script success output in one file and error in another log file?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, logging, scripting

sh -x script.sh

#If the script.sh executes successfully, the output should go to a file called success.log and if the script fails to execute successfully, the output should go to failure.log ; Note I want the -x debug output in the log files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line :

```
 sh -x script.sh >> /tmp/output 2>&1;if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then mv /tmp/output failure.log; else mv /tmp/output success.log; fi
```

- Redirect full output (faillure/debug) on temp file ( 2&>1 to catch every stderr and stdoud flow)
- Catch the return value (*$?*) of the latest command
- Move the temp file to correct target in consideration of return value (*if then*)

Comment: This solution won't output the debug messages as requested by the poster.

Comment: It depends of which sh is used. I've made a test on osx it works.